# tinymce 4.0.11 does not show icons in toolbar and image browse button shows Error visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tinymce

I am using tinymce 4.0.11, the toolbar icons are not visible, and when i click the insert image button it shows modal popup for file upload, but when i click on "Browse" button, it shows error:

Error
Server returned an invalid response

Could someone please help me in getting this resolved. I am using Visual Studio 2012 with .Net 4.5.

Thanks,

Harish

Comment: which browser ? IE 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

this bug is still open on tinymce bug tracker ...

tinymce renders this buttons by content property of CSS. because content property is not supported in old IE Browsers it will rendered as boxicons

here is a bug [Bug Link](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=6351)

here is a screenshot

[Screenshot of tinymce with blank toolbar icons..](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_download.php?file=1211)